# Best way to share custom PHP code amongst projects

Tags: php, components, versioning, distributed, share

I'm developing a distributed environment, mostly in PHP.
A lot of the projects that I have share some of the same code. For example my logging code (based on log4php but with some custom additions).

I can just copy-paste this code in every project, but naturally, if I change anything in it I need to re-paste it everywhere and 'hope' it doesn't change anything.
Obviously not a good way.

Now, I was wondering: what is the best and simplest way of sharing this code?
I'm hoping there is something as easy as making your own private PEAR-like channel? Do people do this for this use case? Or is there an ever easier way? I rather not start with inter-dependent repositories etc. If it matters though, I use Mercurial for versioning.

Thanks all.

Comment: Going to use the method that Jens Struwe describes, with the Mercurial subrepo's that linepogl informed me about. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps the best way (I am using too) is to host the common code in a versioning system such as Git or Mercurial or SVN and checkout this code in each related project. As long such a project does not have updates you can continue to work on your common code. In the case you want to touch a project again that utilizes the common code, you need to perform a source code update or pull. Then you update your project sources according to the changes of the common source base.

Comment: This combined with genesis's suggestion regarding include_path is the way to go in my opinion. With Git, you could even use submodules, dunno 'bout HG

Comment: May be, but you might use the code from different machines. Also, different projects might use different versions of the common code, so you will need probably several copies of the repository.

Comment: You could achieve that easily with Git or SVN. I believe you can tell git submodule which exact commit you want, and with SVN, you can use svn:externals with a specific commit as well. This way you can use the version of the code you want, I'm sure HG has something for this too.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick replies already. But wouldn't it be less complex to make your own, maybe somehow private, PEAR channel and publish the components there? I'm not sure that that is even possible though. But indeed, giving those components their own repository might be the best solution.

Comment: I would not go with this PEAR for the main reason that using a versioning tool is broader accepted and better documented.

Answer (score 1):

What about include_path PHP directive?

Just add `include_path`, for example `/usr/share/php5/`

and include your file like `yourfile.php` from each project

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, that might be a good alternative for some. Not really for me though, it's hard to see this scale.

Answer (score 1):

Use Git or Mercurial for that. In both of them, you can create sub-modules or sub-repositories.

http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-submodule.html

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Subrepository

Comment: Thanks, didn't know of the concept of a sub-repository yet in Mercurial.