# How reuse custom code among projects using PHP natively?

Tags: php

I am not familiar with PHP and having a background in C#.

I would like to know if PHP offers a way to share custom code among projects natively in the language (targeting the latest version of PHP)?

As in C# there is the possibility to create a custom DLL, that can be included in other projects when needed in order to reuse some code.

- Does PHP offer a similar feature?
- Does PHP packages related on that?
- Can [PHP namespace](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php) be useful in this scenario?
- What bout the use of include?
- If PHP does not offer this support, which project/library can be used?

I understand there is the possibility to share common code from a versioning system such SVN and checkout sharedcode in each related project (as described in other answer on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6891071/best-way-to-share-custom-php-code-amongst-projects)), but I am interested in the possibility in the language itself.

Comment: You can create a library of classes and/or functions in the form of a framework, or use a 3rd party framework outright.

Comment: you can use `abstract class` and declare some common property or method, then you can extends from that class and reuse the code.http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php

Comment: @Rasclatt thanks for your comment, could you please point  me out a link to this PHP feature or the name of some related framework? Thanks for your help on this.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://getcomposer.org/doc/02-libraries.md)

Comment: A little side info: so far I know there is a framework call falcon its engine build by C https://phalconphp.com/en/

Comment: Are you after something other than including a file that recursively includes your project files? Or extending a parent?

Comment: Did you check https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md? It creates an autoloader with generated namespaces and you can use your private repos too.

Comment: @Chris I would like to know for both. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think with [phar archives](http://docs.php.net/phar) and [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) you get as close to [assemblies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hk5f40ct%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and [nuget](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/p/nugetpackages.aspx) as you can get.

Answer (score 0):

You should try a php framework like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) or [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/). If you don't want to try a framework, there are couple of ways.

You can create a `class` of functions and then you can `include` that `class` wherever you want in your scripts. This is a simplest example.

`namespaces` are your friends. I highly recommend yo to have a look at [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/object-oriented-php-for-beginners--net-12762) for PHP and [here](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals) for a PHP framework.

Answer (score 0):

You can share code with composers packages, more on:

```
https://packagist.org/
https://getcomposer.org/
```